# Kendo Mvvm Dynamic grid view Edit issue

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I am building the kendo grid view from the Database, i am able to bind the grid view , how ever i could not able to edit. grid cell is not closing after edit the value. Please refer the link below.

[https://jsfiddle.net/09jqht85](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have tried with the Kendo UI  sites and blogs.